# If Statement Comparing Strings

Tags: java

I've 'finished' a program that converts Celcius to Fahrenheit and vice versa, typical beginner stuff.

However, my if statement always activates even when the conditions are not met, and I am almost positive that I have the correct syntax for != as it relates to strings, yet the program still prints the if statement's print line regardless of what I enter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TemperatureConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      double temp = 0.0;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.printf("Please enter the type of temperature conversion you need to perform: ");
      String type = in.nextLine();

      if (!type.equals("F") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("c")){
                System.out.println("Invalid conversion, must supply either C or F, program will exit");
                System.exit(0); }

        switch (type) {
            case "F":
                System.out.printf("\nPlease enter the temperature to be converted to Celsius: ");
                temp = in.nextDouble();
                double fToC = (temp - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
                System.out.printf ("\nThe equivalent temperature in Celsius is %.3f\n", fToC);
                break;

            case "f":
                System.out.printf("Please enter the temperature to be converted to Celsius: ");
                temp = in.nextDouble();
                fToC = (temp - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
                System.out.printf ("\nThe equivalent temperature in Celsius is %.3f\n", fToC);
                break;

            case "C":
                System.out.printf("Please enter the temperature to be converted to Fahrenheit: ");
                temp = in.nextDouble();
                double cToF = (temp * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
                System.out.printf ("\nThe equivalent temperature in Fahrenheit is %.3f\n", cToF);
                break;

           case "c":
                System.out.printf("Please enter the temperature to be converted to Fahrenheit: ");
                temp = in.nextDouble();
                cToF = (temp * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32;
                System.out.printf ("\nThe equivalent temperature in Fahrenheit is %.3f\n", cToF);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you should probably have an else statement for the switch..just do else { switch() {} }

Comment: In Java 7 you can `switch` on a String, but it would be cleaner in your code to just break the switch statement up into a series of if/else statements.

Comment: you forgot **else** before switch cases

Comment: Eliminate the `if` statement entirely and use `default` in your `switch` instead.

Comment: if (!(type.toLowerCase().equals("f")||type.toLowerCase().equals("c")))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
!type.equals("F") || !type.equals("f")
```

This is always true. Why? This means "If type is not F or type is not f". There are three cases:

- Type equals "F", and type does not equal "f". `false || true == true`
- Type does not equal "F", and type equals "f". `true || false == true`
- Type does not equal "F", and type does not equal "f". `true || true == true`

This would be false if type was both "f" and "F" at the same time, which is impossible.

You want to use `&&` instead of `||`. Alternatively, keep using `||`, but move the `!`s like this:

```
if (!(type.equals("F") || type.equals("f") || type.equals("C") || type.equals("c")))
```

which might be closer to what you were thinking of when you wrote the if statement.

Also, you can make that a bit shorter by using equalsIgnoreCase instead of checking both the uppercase and lowercase versions.

Comment: Thanks, && worked wonders, and the IgnoresCase I'm sure will be useful for future projects too.

Answer (score 1):

for the If condition you can simply write :

`if (!(type.toLowerCase().equals("f") ||type.toLowerCase().equals("c")))`

```
 if (!(type.toLowerCase().equals("f") ||type.toLowerCase().equals("c"))){
            System.out.println("Invalid conversion, must supply either C or F, program will exit");
          System.exit(0); 
  }

  else{
// switch cases
```

Answer (score 0):

`!type.equals("F") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("c")`
this will always return true;
you should change `||` to `&&`

Comment: otherwise it will always `System.exit(0);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!type.equals("F") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("c"))
```

Simple add a parentheses (between !type) to make the "not" distributed to each variable.

```
if (!(type.equals("F") || !type.equals("f") || !type.equals("C") || !type.equals("c")))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative is to use the String's contains() method:

```
if (!"CcFf".contains(type)) { ... }
```